# How can I change INVITE message in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, invite

I am very new in Asterisk. Hope my question is achievable.

My question:

When sip client A calls sip client B through my asterisk server, I want to make a change to the INVITE message which asterisk server send to clientB.

More detail:

The following message is original message sent from Asterisk server to clientB, where "3000" is clientA's userName and "666" is clientA's displayedName (or caller ID in Zoiper APP). I want to swap "3000" and "666" in the message. Either changing .c code or changing .conf is great. 
Does anybody could give a hint where to modify SIP INVITE message to sipB when asterisk server receives SIP INVITE from sipA.

```
INVITE sip:3001@192.168.60.35;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.60.4:40416;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---cfa0bdc915e1bba8;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:3000@192.168.60.4:40416;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:3001@192.168.60.35;transport=UDP>
From: "666"<sip:3000@192.168.60.35;transport=UDP>;tag=6a4be72e
Call-ID: DqIzNYN2-TZwiTSB7JdwGQ..
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Content-Type: application/sdp
User-Agent: Zoiper rv2.8.40
Allow-Events: presence, kpml, talk
Content-Length: 240
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this from dialplan. It's a simple swap of variables:

```
Set(TEMP=${CALLERID(name)})
Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)})
Set(CALLERID(num)=${TEMP})
```

Please also refer to the documentation with the CLI command: `core show function CALLERID`

Comment: This method works great! However, your last line is incorrect. 
Set(${CALLERID(num)}=${TEMP}) should be Set(CALLERID(num)=${TEMP}). 
Thank you very much.